# Generating sequence in R

Tags: r, numbers, sequence, sequences

I need to generate the numbers from 2 to 100 excluding the numbers (11,21,31,41 etc).

I know to do 2 to 100 is simply 2:100 but I am uncertain how I would go about excluding certain values.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @JackManey Very nice link, although I fear the OP might not read it entirely. After all, it would require some effort put into that as there's really a lot of words to read...

Answer (score 2):

probably not too elegant but works.

```
  c(1:100)[-seq(from=1, to=91, by=10)]
```

however, your question could have been improved ;)

Comment: @AndresT you are absolutely right... sorry for that fault. I had initially chosen the `c(1:100)` attempt and then noticed that this includes the 1 - unfortunately I changed the 1 for a 2 without thinking!